# Page numbering of titlepages

Tags: page-numbering

I have a document of type "report" and I want to have several title pages separated by blank pages. I want these pages to be excluded from the numbering. Then after the title pages I want to have an abstract, with roman page numbering and only after that start the arabic pagenumbering.

My problem now is that the roman page numbering of my abstract starts with "ii", and not with "i", as it should (if the title pages are not counted). So I want to make Latex start counting the pages from the abstract. Obviously now it counts one of the title pages.

In order to generate the title pages I'm using the command
`\begin{titlepage} ... \end{titlepage}`.
I tried putting the `\thispagestyle{empty}`, but it does not change the numbering in the abstract.

Do you have any ideas how I could fix this?

Here is my code (sorry for the long post):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, outer=1in, inner=1.5in, includefoot, headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{afterpage}
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}

\pagenumbering{roman}                  % Sets the pagenumbering to Roman nunerals to 

\begin{document}

\afterpage{\blankpage}
\begin{titlepage}
       Here is my 1st titlepage!
       \vfill
\end{titlepage}


\afterpage{\blankpage}
\begin{titlepage}
       Here is my 2nd titlepage!
       \vfill
\end{titlepage}


\afterpage{\blankpage}
\begin{titlepage}
       Here is my 3d titlepage!
       \vfill
\end{titlepage}

\chapter*{Abstract}
        Here is my abstract with page numbering "ii".

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
        Here is my introduction.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you reduce your document to a minimal and **complete** one please? Most of the packages is not needed for the particular topic of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `\pagestyle{empty}` in the title page part using `\cleardoublepage` after `\end{titlepage}`. Use `\pagenumbering{alph}` in order to keep `hyperref` happy, in case you end up using it.

After the last title page, switch to `\pagenumbering{roman}` for the abstract, then to `\pagenumbering{arabic}` for the main text.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[top=1in,
   bottom=1in,
   outer=1in,
   inner=1.5in,
   includefoot,
   headheight=13.6pt
]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{alph}% just to keep hyperref happy, if you use it

\begin{titlepage}
       Here is my 1st titlepage!
       \vfill
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage

\begin{titlepage}
       Here is my 2nd titlepage!
       \vfill
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage

\begin{titlepage}
       Here is my 3d titlepage!
       \vfill
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage

\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter*{Abstract}

Here is my abstract with page numbering "i".

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}

Here is my introduction.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with the `etoolbox` package, and an `abstract environment`. The code in the body of the document was simplified:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{titlepage}{\pagenumbering{gobble}}
\AtEndEnvironment{titlepage}{\vfill\cleardoublepage}
\apptocmd{\abstract}{\pagenumbering{roman}\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}
\AtEndEnvironment{abstract}{\vfill\clearpage\pagestyle{empty}}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, outer=1in, inner=1.5in, includefoot, headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  Here is my 1st titlepage!
\end{titlepage}

\begin{titlepage}
  Here is my 2nd titlepage!
\end{titlepage}

\begin{titlepage}
  Here is my 3rd titlepage!
\end{titlepage}

\begin{abstract}
  Here is my abstract with roman page numbering and page number \thepage
\end{abstract}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
Here is my introduction.

\end{document}
```

[image]